# Uso de resource controller

Tags: vue.js, controller

Estoy intentando poblar una tabla dinamica usando Vue, pero al llamar al controlador de recursos, me devuelve el json y me elimina la vista,donde esta la tabla, he revisado y probado con varias formas de llamar al controlador en al ruta, pero nada. Aqui el código

ruta

```
    Route::get('/gestionarvehiculos','VehiculosController@gestion');
    Route::resource('gestionarvehiculos', 'VehiculoController');
```

Controlador

```
public function index()
    {
         $vehiculos = Vehiculo::get();   

         return $vehiculos;               
    }
```

Vista

```
....
 <table class="table table-hover  table-sprite">
           <thead>
             <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Matricula</th>
              <th>Marca</th>
              <th>Modelo</th>
              <th>Capacidad</th>
              <th>Fabricacion</th>
              <th>Color</th>
              <th>Estado</th>
              <th>Editar</th>
              <th>Borrar</th>
              <th colspan="2">&nbsp</th>
             </tr> 
           </thead>
             <tbody>
                <tr v-for="vehiculo in parque">
                  <td width="100px">@{{vehiculo.id}}</td>
                  <td width="100px">@{{vehiculo.matricula}}</td>
                  <td width="100px">@{{vehiculo.marca}}</td>
                  <td width="100px">@{{vehiculo.modelo}}</td>
                  <td width="100px">@{{vehiculo.capacidad}}</td>
                  <td width="100px">@{{vehiculo.fabricacion}}</td>
                  <td width="100px">@{{vehiculo.color}}</td>
                  <td width="100px">@{{vehiculo.estado}}</td>
                  <td width="10px"><a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Editar</a>  </td>
                  <td width="10px"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Borrar</a>  </td>
                </tr>  
             </tbody>
       </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
       <pre>
          @{{$data | json}}      
       </pre>
    </div>
```

app.js

```
require('./bootstrap'); 

 window.Vue = require('vue'); 



const app = new Vue({

    el: '#crud',         

    created: function(){
        this.getVehiculos();
    },

    data:{
        parque: []
    },
    methods: {
        getVehiculos: function() {

            var urlVehiculos = 'gestionarvehiculos';

            axios.get(urlVehiculos).then(response => {
            this.parque = response.data
            }) 
        }
    },


});
```

¿que esta mal?

Comment: Hola, ¿éstas intentando usar vue.js con php?, ¿Podrias adjuntar tú archivo javascript?

Comment: Deberías retornar la vista , y pasar los valores a ella , como está actualmente solo retornas la colección de datos que Laravel automáticamente convierte a Json

Comment: Adjunte el js, para como me indicó @cjra, tal vez asi se entienda mejor